# Can I refer to single value of foreign key in Django's template?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I have model:

```
`class product(models.Model):
    product = models.CharField(primary_key=True, unique=True, max_length=7, editable=False)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=50)

 class pricelist(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price_group = models.ForeignKey(pricegroup, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, null=True)`
```

Basically I have 4 different price groups(one product may have up to 4 different prices- one for each price_group) and I'd like to display product's price of specified(filtered) price group on my product's template(DetailView).

Let's say I have following price groups: "PG1", "PG2","PG3","PG4"

I'm able to loop through the list of them:

```
{% for pricelist in product.pricelist.all %}
                    {{ pricelist.price }}
              {% endfor %}
```

but I can't display prices for only two specified price groups.
I need to display prices on my webpage in the following way:

```
PG1 = 124
PG3 = 367
```

Sometimes only prices for two or three groups are available

Comment: It may be a database architecture issue. If there is a fixed number of four price_group only, why would you be using ForeignKey fields? Why not use a CharField with `choice` element for four groups only?

Comment: Groups are synchronized with external system and in the future their number might grow.
Thanks for the comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, following @tstoev answer I got this working with decorator:

```
   @property
def PricePG1(self):
   return pricelist.objects.filter(price_group__exact='PG1',  product_id=self)[0].price
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you need to pre-render the data in the view and then pass it to the template as context. There is a hacky option to use custom filters in the template, but even those would require additional information to work.